# Add user from domain without adding to domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain

I understand the following doesn't seem to make much sense, but I have a specialized piece of software that requires me to do this to properly interact with a machine.

I have a windows 2008 server.  I need to add a domain user to the local admin group without adding the machine itself  to the domain.  Is this possible?  If so how?

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible at all.

In order to grant permissions to domain users on a computer (including adding them to local groups), the computer needs to be joined to the domain.

Comment: I didn't think it was. The software does not seem to be able to handle being added to the domain.  It worked fine as a workgroup, but stopped working when I added it to a domain.

Comment: Problem is the users workstations are now part of the domain.  So the server no longer can communicate with the users.

Comment: It seems like the developers did a lazy implementation of integrated windows authorization.  I'll have to figure out another work around